# Is it possible to know if an app has advertisements by analyzing permissions?

Tags: permissions, ads

Or if not, how to see if an app has advertisements or not?

Comment: Many apps that do have ads, require access to Internet. On the other hand, many other apps without ads do require such permissions as well. So, no. There's no "foolproof" way to know if an app has ads by just looking at the permissions.

Answer (score 27):

You cannot see that just by checking an app's permissions: those permissions ad modules require for their job are the same the app itself might need for another job. You can, however, look up the app at [AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/): for each app, that site lists up what ad modules (and other libraries) are used. You find that scrolling down to the "Libraries" section. *AppBrain* distinguishes between "Development tools" (which also include analytic libraries like *Google Analytics* or *Flurry*), "Social libraries" (Facebook & Co), and "Ad network libraries" (Admob & Co).

[image: Libraries]
<sup>Libraries used by an app as shown by [AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/)</sup>

Clicking on an entry also reveals details on that module/network.