# Is it possible for an application to deliver ads while requesting NO permission from the user?

Tags: applications, internet, permissions, ads

I know that for an app to access the internet it does not need the "Full network access" permission. In the android system it says that an app can use the browser to access the internet. The permission is needed only for "custom protocols".

So is it possible to deliver ads without requesting permission from the user?

Comment: Ads can be inbuilt too.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/140808/is-it-possible-to-know-if-an-app-has-advertisements-by-analyzing-permissions

Answer (score 2):

Apps do not require any sort of permission to show things on the screen — that is a basic function of the majority of apps, after all.  And there is no reason that what they show you can't be an ad.  Ads are just data that doesn't have to be treated differently from any other type of data.

Comment: Yes but most ads are downloaded from the internet. They are not regular data that an app has in it.

Comment: @yoyo_fun I have several apps with built-in ads that were not downloaded but, regardless, they ARE "regular data".  As you've already noted in your question, apps don't need permissions for basic internet access, which is transmitting and receiving data.  That data can include ads.  There is nothing special about ad data other than how it is interpreted.

Comment: Thanks. It is more clear now. I thought that ads are something generated by Google or other ad provider and they have to keep track of how many ads the user has seen to know how much money they have to pay to the app publisher. But I believe they can do that with basic internet access (if they do it)